# How to show a window on multi-screen by using C++ on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, screen

I would like to show a window on top of all screen on Windows 10 of current PC/laptop but I didn't find the way to do it.

[Story]
1. When application runs, it shows a window with message on top of screen.
2. If there are many screen (ex: plugin HDMI, Digital port... -> extend screen occurs), this window will be top of all screens.

If you have the way or idea to resolve this problem on Windows 10, please teach me.

Comment: Do you want to *duplicate* the window on all connected screens? Or just make it large enough so the single window covers all screens?

Comment: Yes, I want to duplicate the window on all connected screens.